# Managing JQueryUI Sortable in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use the **JQueryUI Sortable** (version 1.12.1) method in a **TypeScript** (version 3.2.1) development.  Generally, this has been a relatively straightforward experience, but I have run into a problem trying to implement the *Sortable Widget's* `helper` option.  In *TypeScript* my code looks like this:

```
$('.connected-sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.connected-sortable',
    delay: 150,
    helper: (evt: Event, item: JQueryUI.Sortable) => {
        // How can I work with the JQueryUI.Sortable object?
        // I really want a JQuery<HTMLElement> or even a 
        // plain Element as I want to do manipulate it.

        // The following fails:
        // Property 'hasClass' does not exist on type 'Sortable'
        item.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

I want to be able to access the `JQueryUI.Sortable` object as with a `JQuery<HTMLElment>` or even a plain `Element` but I cannot find a way to convert/access the underlying item.  For reference, my code runs in plain old JavaScript as it is based upon this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQnWG/480/).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You target the sortable object using `ui.item`.

On the sortable `start` function you could addClass, and on stop removeClass;

```
$('.connected-sortable').sortable({
  connectWith: '.connected-sortable',
  delay: 150,
  helper: (evt: Event, item: JQueryUI.Sortable),
  start: function(event,ui) {
    ui.item.addClass('selected');
  },
  stop: function(event,ui) {
    ui.item.removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```